# How to make a categorical count bar plot with time on x-axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to count the number of occurrences of categories in a variable and plot it against time.

The data looks like following:

```
Date_column    Categorical_variable
20-01-2019            A
20-01-2019            B
20-01-2019            C
21-01-2019            A
21-02-2019            A
22-02-2019            B
........................
23-04-2020            A
```

I want to show that in month of Jan I had 1 occurrence of B/C whereas 2 occurrences of A. In feb, I had 1 occurrence of A/B and so on. The bar plots can be stacked to know the total number of occurrences.

I've been very close to it. But haven't been able to draw plot out of it.

```
df['Date_column'].groupby([df.Date_column.dt.year, df.Date_column.dt.month]).agg('count')
```

The other way is to change the dates to 1st of every month, and then group by to count a occurence. But I'm unable to draw plot out of it.

```
df.groupby(df['Date_column'], df['Categorical_variable']).count()
```

[image: An example of what I need. This is not according to the data. Timeline will run into few more years]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df['Date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_column'])


df = pd.crosstab(df['Date_column'].dt.to_period('m'), df['Categorical_variable'])


df.plot.bar()
```

Comment: The data runs into another year. So on x-axis i need both month and the year.

Comment: @AvinashKumar - Can you check now?